# mod_headers set cookie expire date

Tags: apache, cookies, header

Currently, I'm using this code in my Apache config to save a cookie on an image request:

```
<FilesMatch "^image\.jpg$">
Header set Set-Cookie: "cookiename=value"
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I set the cookie expiry date? I tried googling it but came up with nothing..

Thanks,

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I haven't found a way to calculate a date within the apache conf file.